# SQL - Join two tables but only show specific value

Tags: sql, database

Alright so I've created a database called news which contains few tables with different information in them. I have two table's one named **Employee**'s and the other table is called **Article**'s. 
Now what I would like to receive from Employee tabel is Name(The names of the Employee's) and Title. And from the Article table I would like it to show what type of Article every Employee has been on and writen since they are connected through the ArticleID. But I would only like for a specific ArticleID to show for example numer 2. Here is an example of the output I would like to show.

```
                   Titel         Name            ArticleID   
                   Redirector    Jonas              2
                   journalist    Clark              2
                   journalist    Louise             2
```

This is how far I've goten with my SQL code but  I cant get it to work, they error i'm getting says that p.Employee does not exsist.

```
 SELECT p.Titel, p.Name, ap.ArticleID
    FROM Employee p join
         Article ap
         on p.Employee  = ap.Article
    WHERE ap.ArticleID IN (2);
```

Some help on this would be appreciated.

Edit -----------------
How the table structure looks. I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Table Employee

```
EmployeeID  Name    UserName    Pass      Titel         PhoneNumer 
    1       Clark    xxxxxx      a      journalist       12356465
    2       Louise   aaaaaa      b      journalist       45648984
    3       Jonas    bbbbbb      c      Redirector       489489448
```

Table Article

```
 ArticleID      KategoriID       preamble    Body   headlines         Published
    1              1             dwadwad
    2              2              qweqw
    3              3              dwqdqw
```

Comment: Provide table structure (schema) of both table. Problem area is `on p.Employee  = ap.Article` it should be something like `on p.ArticleID= ap.ArticleID` basically common column

Comment: Does the table `Employee` actually have a column named `Employee`? If so, does the table `Article` actually have a column named `Article`? If so, are you sure that those two are the columns that should match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way your query looks now, is as if the tables are connected through Employee.Employee and Article.Article.

The way you describe it, the link is on ArticleID, so it sounds like it should be:

```
SELECT 
  p.Titel, p.Name, ap.ArticleID
FROM 
  Employee p 
  INNER JOIN Article ap
     ON p.ArticleID  = ap.ArticleID
WHERE 
  ap.ArticleID IN (2); -- Or just ` = 2`
```

But I would suspect that an Employee can write multiple articles, in which case it would make more sense that an Article has an EmployeeID, and that EmployeeID defines the relationship:

```
SELECT 
  p.Titel, p.Name, ap.ArticleID
FROM 
  Employee p 
  INNER JOIN Article ap
     ON p.EmployeeID  = ap.EmployeeID
WHERE 
  ap.ArticleID IN (2); -- Or just ` = 2`
```

Though it's reasonable as well that multiple employees could co-author an article. So if you also want to have the possibility that one employee writes multiple articles, you would need a *junctions table*, and your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.Titel, p.Name, ap.ArticleID
FROM 
  Employee p 
  INNER JOIN EmployeeArticle ea
     ON ea.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeID
  INNER JOIN Article ap
     ON ap.ArticleID  = ea.ArticleID
WHERE 
  ap.ArticleID IN (2); -- Or just ` = 2`
```

In that last case, EmployeeArticle, would contain just two fields, EmployeeID and ArticleID, to allow you to link multiple employees to multiple articles (n..m relation). If you don't need any fields from Article itself, you could leave out the join with `Article` and just write:

```
WHERE 
  ea.ArticleID IN (2); -- Or just ` = 2`
```

After all, the ID would already be there in the junction table.

Comment: I agree, it seems like a many to many relation, and that we are missing a table

Comment: Thanks for the really good answer and taking your time. the second query actually helpt me a lot and was the right answer. I apologize for not showing the table structrue and the next time I will have that in my minde :)

Answer (score 1):

Need join `ON` table columns. I think table Employee does not have column Employee and Article ... column Article.

```
SELECT p.Titel, p.Name, ap.ArticleID
    FROM Employee p join
         Article ap
         on p.ArticleID = ap.ID -- for relation Article 1 : N Employee
       --on p.ID = ap.RefToEmployee -- for relation Article N : 1 Employee
    WHERE ap.ArticleID = 2;
```

**EDIT** (after publish tables structure):

```
SELECT p.Titel, p.Name, ae.ArticleID
    FROM Article_Employee ae join
         Employee p
         on p.EmployeeID = ae.EmployeeID
    WHERE ae.ArticleID = 2;
```

Comment: You think that there is a column called ArticleID in Employee ? That should would limit the number of articles an employee can write (only 1 article per employee)

Comment: Also if `Employee` had `ArticleID`, there wouldn't even be a need for a join.

Comment: The second sql query that you provided works perfect, thanks for helping me out! Also I apologize for missing to put on how the structure of the tables look like. :)